Unable to activate usb sound card
I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question.  Hoping I can get some help.
I am a amateur radio operator attempting to use a Digimode 3 sound card interface to transmit and receive digital radio signals.  The Digimode 3 uses a C-Media CM108 chip to send and receive these signals.  I am using the WSJTX program.  The WSJTX program settings allow one to choose the sound card to use to send and receive these signals, for both audio input to the computer, and output to the radio transceiver.  These choices appear in pulldown lists, for input and output. WSJTX 'sees' the C-Media USB card for input only, so I can receive these signals.  It does not see the output for the card, it is simply missing from the list of choices, so I can receive, but not transmit.  No audio can be sent to the radio for transmission.
Interestingly, another computer here works just fine, it receives and transmits normally using the very same Digimode 3 unit.  Both computers run Kubuntu 22.04, it is the much older computer that works fine, the newer one, just two years old, does not.  I have tried various usb ports, to no avail.
I have looked at permissions, and they are identical on both machines.  I think the output side of the card is not being turned on with the newer machine, but I am not sure how to remedy that issue, or even if I am right.
I hope someone can help me with this and that I have explained it clearly enough.
My knowledge of linux is limited, but I can go to the terminal and issue commands, if I know what to input.
Thanks in advance.
Andy

You mention Kubuntu 22.04 LTS & different responses from two different systems, as 22.04 is a LTS release there is kernel stack choice (ie. kernel choice, which alters kernel modules (aka drivers)).  Are your systems using the same? or different? as that may explain difference between your systems, with flavors the install media sets the defaults; 22.04 & 22.04.1 media used the GA kernel stack, 22.04.2 & later media defaulted to HWE kernel stack. *Check you're not using low-latency etc.  If that's the same, I'd then explore hardware differences..  but you gave limited details of that.

gulverc,  thank you for the response.  I'm not sure how to check on the issues you mention.  Both systems are Kubuntu 22.04 LTS and are always updated regularly.  How do I check the kernel choice you mention?  I was not aware that this could be different between the two machines.  I also don't know about low-latency and would not know if I were using that on either machine.  How do I check any of this?

gulverc, I have looked at the info center in Kubuntu.  Software listed there is:  KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7  KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0, QT Version: 5.15.3, Kernel Version: 6.5.0-35 64 bit,, Graphics Platform: X11  .  I don't know if this is the information you require or if it helps at all.  This is all the same on both machines.

The kernel can be gathered using uname -r, which for my system is 6.8.0-31-generic. If both yours report 6.5 and are running 22.04, then both are using the HWE kernel stack.. ASSUMING neither are using different kernels (further detail in that uname output; ie. mine contains generic and not keywords like low latency, oem etc.. which you didn't specify.  64bit tells me nothing as you don't mention if arm64, ppc64el, riscv64, amd64 etc..  though as only ARM has both 32 + 64 bit maybe you do mean arm64?? I don't know..  Your issue maybe hardware related not software

Ok, results of uname -r is: 6.5.0-35-generic.  architecture is amd64.  This is the same for both machines.

I thought I would add something to my original posts.  Thinking I may have a hardware issue, since this is a dual-boot machine, I booted up in Windows 10, instead of Kubuntu 22.04.  My usb sound card works fine in Windows, but no sound out in Kubuntu, the card is not recognized by the WSJTX program.  So my radio station works fine with Windows, but I cannot transmit using Kubuntu.  This at least confirms I have no hardware issue, but seems linux/Kubuntu related.

Sorry, by hardware related..  I meant how the linux kernel deals with hardware  (ie. differences between the hardware of your machines, even if they are the same male/model; components get changed over the years.. I had 5 dell optiplex 755 PCs but no two were identical in all components as none were purchased/made). If it was me; I'd boot live media using the GA kernel (5.15 for 22.04) & see if it works there, as switching from HWE (6.5) to GA (5.15) is easy, but sorry I have no further ideas not knowing your hardware etc.. You can wait for others to respond. (FYI: doing live = no changes)

guiverc, understand completely.  I wanted to be sure myself that I did not have a real hardware issue here.  Trying it with Windows just came to me, since I am dual-boot here, but rarely use anything but Kubuntu.  I may try your ideas though.  If I have no other responses that help me, I may wait until the 24.04 update due in August and try that, using Windows in the meantime.  I prefer not to, but may not have a choice.  At least I know the setup works, that gives me some peace anyway.

Live testing allows you to easily (no packages installed on box) test the released & current Ubuntu setup from thumb-drive... with dailies available of noble (24.04; so newer than released images) & jammy (22.04.5 unreleased image; alas no 6.8 kernel there yet; it's in edge proposed only thus far that I see).... but this will show what updates will achieve (inc. maybe release-upgrade).  As I don't know your actual issue & thus fix, I can't help there sorry.

guiverc,  I will probably try live testing in order to get this all going the way i want it.  Right now I am using two computers, one Windows to run the radio, one linux to do everything else.  The volume controls I need to control the equipment are just tough to use in Windows, much much easier with a linux system, easily accessible too.  What I am doing now is the quick way to get the station running again.  This will all not last long as I will have to find a linux alternative.  This will all get fixed up, somehow I always manage to get things going the way I wish.

Another comment on my situation.  I ran some live testing with Andys Ham Radio Linux.  Another Andy, not I.  My station is now working properly, audio input/output working on each radio the way it should.  I'm not sure what happened to the Kubuntu system here, but I'm sure it was some change I made along the way.  Only wish I knew what I did to cause it, so I don't do it again!  The new system has lots of stuff pre-installed so I didn't have to piece things back together from scratch.  It saved a lot of effort.
